# Change URL based on the tab clicked

Tags: php, html, jquery, tabs

I have 2 tabs, I'll like to set URL based on the tab clicked. I have tried suggested options suggested on SO, but I have not resolve it.
An example using jQuery

```
$("#home-tab").click({
    window.location.href="http://mydomain/url";
})
```

These are the tabs

```
<?php if ( Config( 'CREATE_USER' ) ) : ?>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">User</a>
                            </li>
                            <?php endif;

                            if ( Config( 'CREATE_BUSINESS' ) ) : ?>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Student</a>
                            </li>
                            <?php endif;?>
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Didn't work either. I got this on the console - ```Autofocus processing was blocked because a document's URL has a fragment '#profile'.```

Comment: Not really clear what you actually want here. The JS snippet you have shown makes it appear you wanted to go to a different page? But if that is the case, then why would these be tabs, and not normal links to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$("#home-tab").on("click",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href="http://mydomain/url";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you are passing an object as a parameter to the click handler, you should pass a function

your jQuery code should be :

```js
$("#home-tab").click(function () {
    window.location.href="http://mydomain/url";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not necessary, and **window.location.replace(...)** will best simulate an HTTP redirect. You can change URL to us it.
If you want to simulate someone clicking on a link, use **location.href**

sets href property explicitly.

```
window.location = "http://mydomain/url";
```

does it implicitly Since window.location returns an object, which by default sets its .href property.

```
window.location.replace("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

ike attr() method (after jQuery 1.6 introduce)

```
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
$(location).prop('href', url);
```

If you want to simulate someone clicking on a link, use `location.href`

If you want to simulate an HTTP redirect, use `location.replace`